# laravel policy not working, lament is instance of Post not given

Tags: php, laravel, post, authorization, comments

Strange thing.
I set up a policy that gets 3 variables:

```
public function deleteComment(User $user, Comment $comment, Post $post){
  //logic
}
```

Then have a blade view like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $i)

  @foreach ($i->comments as $c)

    @can('deleteComment', $c, $i)

      //show delete button

    @endcan

  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

error returned:

```
Argument 3 passed to App\Policies\CommentPolicy::deleteComment() must be an instance of App\Post, none given
```

instead of showing the button.

Comment: As it say you're calling your deleteComment function with null in your third param and it should be a instance of Post. Add the your code´s part in which you call this function.

Comment: the code part where the function is called is right there :@can('deleteComment', $c, $i)

Comment: Its not, @can only check if User have access to that function. Somewhere between your controller you use deleteComment(), please check it.

Comment: hm, isn't that passing both the comment $c and post $i and checking in the policy if the user can delete the comment then if so show the button? For instance I am using a similar policy: public function seePostOptions(User $user, Post $post); to check if the user is able to see some options (edit etc) and it works like this. No controller is involved here. I mean, I am not trying to delete the comment yet, I am only trying to show the delete button and that should just work.

Comment: Wait, now I am not entirely sure the @can directive accepts more than two arguments...

Comment: check my answer, I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

found the correct way:

```
@can('deleteComment', [$c, $i])
```

So it works.